# How to make a game clock that handles fps and updates separately?

Tags: java

Currently I have an abstract GameClock class that implements runnable and calls an update method which handles both fps and updates with a defined nano second delay. This is the loop:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    launch();
    long nanoPrevious = System.nanoTime();
    long nanoCurrent, nanoElapsed = 0;

    while (running) {
        nanoCurrent = System.nanoTime();
        nanoElapsed += (nanoCurrent - nanoPrevious);
        nanoPrevious = nanoCurrent;

        while (nanoElapsed >= nanoSPU) {
            update(); updates++;
            nanoElapsed -= nanoSPU;
        }
    } finish();
}
```

I'd like to know if this method is lag efficient, and what I could improve, but most importantly how could it handle both fps and updates separately, and how the fps limit could be changed by the user within the game with minimal lag similar to minecraft where you can change your fps cap or set it to unlimited.

Comment: Usually in this type of problem you don't want to catch up on all missed frames (as the while loop seem to imply), but rather compute the frame for the current time instead, and ignore those skipped